# How to use sed to extract a string using a string as search parameter

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to return a string that is constantly changing via the output.
I decided grep and sed might be the best way to handle this.
Basically the output renders a large field of text that contains something to the effect of

```
https://rancher.website.com/version1/proj/abcd123?somethingsomethingsomethingetc
```

the goal is to return the FIRST instance of

```
https://rancher.website.com/version1/proj/
```

as there are multiple, and then return the contents of `abcd123` up to the `?` symbol before it.

I keep trying to tweak the sed command but keep running into errors with my syntax and I am having trouble wrapping my mind around the explanations given so far. I think one of my problems might be around the fact that the sed "search" for lack of a better term, is being run against a string rather than a single character. Also the forward slashes are a problem as I think those are being interpreted as operators in the sed command?

Command I am trying to use is more or less:

```
grep 'https://rancher.website.com/version1/projects/' grep.txt | sed 's/^.*'https:\/\/rancher.website.com\/version1\/projects\/'//g'
```

With grep.txt being the container for the output text of the initial command

Comment: If you only want to find the first match, use `grep -m 1`

Comment: You have extra quotes in the `sed` command. Get rid of the quote before `https` and after `\/`. Then the backslashes before all the other `/` characters will work as desired to prevent it from being treated as an operator.

Comment: @Barmar. Okay, I have done that, but it then just gives me an input field like it is expecting something more, rather than giving me a return. Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: That happens if you have unmatches quotes.

Comment: @Barmar, Okay scratch that, I think my Ubuntu shell was just freezing up as it does. But Do you know how to isolate the return to everything up to "?somethingsomethingsomethingetc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace everything up to the last `/` and everything from `?` with empty strings.

```
grep -m 1 'https://rancher.website.com/version1/projects/' grep.txt | 
    sed -e 's#.*/##' -e 's#\?.*##'
```

When the pattern includes `/`, use a different character as the `s` delimiter to avoid having to escape it; I've used `#` above.